# CSS Nav bar not spanning

Tags: html, css

How do I get my nav bar to span my web page? I have it set up to be 850px. The container div is set up to be 850px.

Here's the link and the code:
http://matthewtbrown.com/jeffandcricketquilt/index2.html

```
nav {
width:850px;
}
nav li {
                font-family: 'bitterregular';
                font-size:16px;
            }
    nav ul {
                background: #000; /* Old browsers */
                list-style: none;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-table;
            }
    nav ul:after {
                content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
            }
    nav ul ul {
                display: none;
            }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
                display: block;
            }
    nav ul li {
                float: left;
                color:#fff;
            }

    nav ul li:hover a {
                color:#FFF;
            }
    nav ul li a {
                display: block;
                padding: 10px 40px;
                color:#FFF;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
    nav ul ul {
                background: #FFF;
                border-radius: 0px; 
                padding: 0;
                position: absolute; 
                top: 100%;
            }
    nav ul ul li {
                float: none; 
                border-top: 1px solid #444;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
                border-color:#FFF;                  
                position: relative;
                background-color:#000;
                font-size:12px;
            }
    nav ul ul li a {
                padding: 8px 40px;
                color:#FFF;             }   
    nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background-color:#000;
                color:#999;
                                }
    nav ul  li a:hover {
                background-color:#000;
                color:#999;
                                }
    nav ul ul ul {
                position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<ul>` doesn't automatically fill the width of the 850-pixel container `<div>`. Set the `<ul>` width to 100% and it will.

```
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `nav` is 850px, however your black background ( `ul` ) is not.

To solve: Set the black background to `nav` instead.

Comment: are you sure? please explain.

Comment: title itself, it is not the background-color that he is asking. Can be a solution but not the 'good' solution :)

Comment: Incorrect. CSS is designed to visually adjust the user experience. The ultimate goal is to make the site looks what the designer expect, instead of fine-tuning the tags arrangement. If tags arrangement has to be adjusted, `ul` should not be used, `div` instead. According to W3C, `ul` is for Un-ordered Listing ONLY.

Answer (score 0):

If having it 100% of the width of the container is what you want just assign the width of `ul` as `100%`